# Can't set light gray accent color

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I'd like to change the accent color of a selected item in a list to light gray, preferably with a bit of opacity. Below is a screenshot of what I want, taken from a different app.

[image: Expected accent color]

In my project, I went under `Assets.xcassets` and set `AccentColor` to this:

[image: my accent color]

But it turns out way darker and without opacity in the app:

[image: actual accent color]

Does anybody maybe know why this is happening?

Below is my view:

```swift
import CoreData
import SwiftUI

struct Sidebar: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext)
    private var viewContext
    
    @FetchRequest(entity: Element.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Element.title, ascending: false)])
    private var elements: FetchedResults<Element>
    
    @AppStorage("SelectedElementId")
    var selectedElementId: String?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            List(selection: self.$selectedElementId) {
                ForEach(self.elements) { element in
                    NavigationLink(destination: ContentView(), tag: element.id!, selection: self.$selectedElementId) {
                        Text(element.title!)
                    }
                }
            }.listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
            
            Button(action: addElement) {
                HStack {
                    Text("Add element")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func addElement() {
        let element = Element(context: viewContext)
        element.id = UUID().uuidString
        element.title = "My title"
        
        self.selectedElementId = element.id
               
        do {
            try self.viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            let nsError = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your code of setting the color and any other related code?

Comment: I've added my view.

Comment: This is actually exactly how `NavigationLink` interact with `accentColor`. You might need to create your custom button view or toggle view.